# SharePoint Search engine issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

I have an issue with SharePoint search engine on people's search page, when i navigate to the page and start searching for user i do not see "x" or "->" elements. How can that be enabled ?

Note: I have to wait till the page loads(3-6 seconds) or refresh every time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not something we can or need to enable.

If you are using the modern search, the two elements only appear when typing in the search box, regardless of which page you are on.

If you are experiencing performance issue, clear the browser cache or switch to another browser to see the result.

[image]

Comment: Basically, i followed the same steps on my side before. With no hesitation it works great. Was problem with other users. Thank you ! I would suggest the same.

Comment: @striker92 No problem! Feel free to come back if you get any progress.